# Why does deadlock occur in this specific WinForms app?

Tags: c#, winforms, deadlock

I create a simple Windows Form with a text box, and Set button and a Toggle button. When I click the Toggle button, a thread is created setting text to the text box repeatedly. When I click the button again, the thread stops. When I click the Set button, a text is set to the text box once. Deadlock occurs if I do the following:

1. Run the app (in debug mode).
2. Click the Toggle button to let text run in the text box.
3. Click Set button. -> Deadlock occurs in this step.

Can you explain why and how deadlock occurs in this situation? How to avoid it?

Below is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DeadLockTest
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DeadLockTest
{
    public class Form1 : Form
    {
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button2;

        private int counter;
        private Thread thread;
        private bool cancelRequested;
        private string content;
        private object lockKey = new object();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected void UpdateContent()
        {
            this.textBox1.Text = this.content;
        }

        protected void InvokeUpdateContent()
        {
            lock (this.lockKey)
            {
                if (InvokeRequired)
                {
                    Invoke(new Action(UpdateContent));
                }
                else
                {
                    UpdateContent();
                }
            }
        }

        protected void SetText(string text)
        {
            this.content = text;
            InvokeUpdateContent();
        }

        protected void StressTest()
        {
            int localCounter = 0;

            while (!this.cancelRequested)
            {
                SetText(string.Format("{0}", localCounter++));
            }

            this.cancelRequested = false;
            this.thread = null;
        }

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.textBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.button2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // textBox1
            // 
            this.textBox1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)(((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)
                        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
            this.textBox1.Name = "textBox1";
            this.textBox1.ReadOnly = true;
            this.textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(260, 20);
            this.textBox1.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 38);
            this.button1.Name = "button1";
            this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.button1.TabIndex = 1;
            this.button1.Text = "Set";
            this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
            // 
            // button2
            // 
            this.button2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(93, 38);
            this.button2.Name = "button2";
            this.button2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.button2.TabIndex = 2;
            this.button2.Text = "Toggle";
            this.button2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button2_Click);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 262);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.textBox1);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SetText(string.Format("{0}", this.counter++));
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.thread == null)
            {
                this.thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(StressTest));

                thread.Start();
            }
            else
            {
                this.cancelRequested = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can you explain why and how deadlock occurs in this situation?

Sure...the deadlock occurs because of the lock()/Invoke() combination.

While the secondary thread is running and updating, it obtains a lock on the object.  Then the secondary thread calls Invoke(), which is a **synchronous** call.  It is key to realize that the secondary thread actually waits for the main UI thread to update the TextBox before continuing.

When you click the Set button, it attempts to update but must wait for the lock to be released by the secondary thread.  At this point the main UI actually stops and freezes at the lock() line waiting for the secondary thread to release the lock.  While waiting for the lock to be released, the main UI thread cannot process any messages.

But what is the secondary thread doing?  It currently has the lock and is waiting for the main UI thread to service its synchronous Invoke() call.  Since the main UI thread is waiting for the lock to be released, though, it cannot service any requests (including Invoke() requests) and bam...DEADLOCK!  They are both waiting for each other.

> How to avoid it?

Never use lock() from the main UI thread.  In some scenarios, switching from Invoke() to BeginInvoke() can solve the problem since BeginInvoke() is asynchronous.